# Prompt ancestor type in a template function

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Say I have an ancestor class, `Component`, and multiple derived classes, `ComponentA`, `ComponentB`, etc.

Now, I write a function that is virtually the same for components `A, B, C, ...`.  So I have a bunch of nearly identical functions (except for type prompts/declaration).

Next, I use a template to re-implement the function, `template <class T> ...`.

This new function works for all components.. But it will not communicate to the user that it is really only compatible with `Components`.

How do I specify a slightly generic function, such that it accepts all objects for which `Component` is an ancestor in terms of inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I specify a slightly generic function, such that it accepts all objects for which `Component` is an ancestor in terms of inheritance?

You can use [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) and [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

Example:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Component {};

class ComponentA : Component {};

class ComponentB : Component {};

template <typename T>
void foo()
{
   static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, "Need a sub-type of Component");
}

int main() 
{
   foo<ComponentA>(); // OK
   foo<ComponentB>(); // OK
   foo<int>();        // Not OK
}
```